# Exit Back Out of Private NPM Repo

Tags: node.js, npm, private, exit, repo

So... I know this is probably a stupid question but I can't seem to find the info anywhere and I figure I can't be the first to ask..

I have been using my companies internally hosted NPM Repo for so long I've forgotten how to get OUT of it and switch back to the public one for a personal project I'm working on...

Cookie to the first person to tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no longer have to choose between one and the other.  If you update to a recent `npm` (latest is 2.6.0), then you can store credentials for multiple repositories in your `.npmrc` file.

You can switch between registries with the `--registry` command line option:

`npm --registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ install jshint
npm --registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ publish`

etc.

You can then set up `publishConfig` settings in your `package.json` to record which packages should be published to which repository.  See https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#publishconfig

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `~/.npmrc` configuration file.  There could also be a file by the same name in your project directory.